# Is the site 'i.stack.infuriating.com' affiliated with Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, specific-question, images

The (now deleted) questing in Biology SE [Why female mosquito not considered as a parasites?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/84340/27918) appears to contain an embedded image but it is not displaying for me.

The URL is shown below, it looks similar to the Stack Exchange imgur image URL except that is *literally infuriating:*

```
https://i.stack.infuriating.com/eNF0P.jpg
```

Is this URL associated with Stack Exchange? Could it be potentially dangerous?

Comment: It is spam., That site and image loads over an http connection, not over https.

Comment: @rene No, it does not seem like spam to me. It contained a space between the image description and URL, causing it to not render.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog my mod flag was helpful

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems to me like the user was manually typing in Markdown on their smartphone, and it decided to, well, make corrections.

As an Android (Google Keyboard) user, I can tell you that when typing in Markdown for links, it wants to automatically put a space between the description's ending `]` and the URL's beginning `(`. Also, it has a tendency to "correct" words based on a dictionary, and it seems like the word "imgur" got auto-converted to "infuriating".

When I change the URL to `imgur.com` and delete the added space, I [get a valid Imgur image that seems to be relevant to the question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/58107), whereas the old URL wasn't a valid image URL. This leads me to believe that it wasn't spam, unlike what rene said in a comment.

Comment: Must have been autocorrect then.

Comment: I'm still a little confused, what happened to the appearance of `infuriating` within the url? Is that part of an autocomplete?

Comment: @uhoh Yes. I've been the victim of such "helpful" typing corrections many times when using my phone's keyboard.

Comment: that must have been quite infuriating!

Comment: @uhoh I bet imgur is not in the phones' dictionary. Infuriating enough infuriating is and it deemed close enough to go as correction for imgur ...